# VBA Excel : inserted code into other workbook doesn't execute workbooks.open command

Tags: excel, vba, file-io, insert

Im injecting code from thisworkbook to other workbooks which will execute some sub into Workbook_BeforeSave. I have to do this in order to save the content of a worksheet into a centralised workbook. I have 1 central workbook and 100 satellites.

One of the inserted command is :

```
set workbooktostore = workbooks.open(storefile)
```

This command is not executing at all when i save the workbooks at the end of the injection. I don't have this issue when the user click on save from the satellite file.

Here an example:

```
Public sub Main
    dim workbooktoinject as workbook
    set workbooktoinject = workbooks.add

    INSERTVBCODE(workbooktoinject)
    workbooktoinject.saveas "C:\satellite1.xlsm", xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
End Sub

Private Sub INSERTVBCODE(WorkbookToUpdate As Workbook)
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim LineNum As Long
    Set VBProj = WorkbookToUpdate.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    CodeMod.InsertLines LineNum, "Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)"
    LineNum = LineNum + 1
    CodeMod.InsertLines LineNum, "    dim workbooktostore as workbook"
    LineNum = LineNum + 1
    CodeMod.InsertLines LineNum, "    dim storefile as string"
    LineNum = LineNum + 1
    CodeMod.InsertLines LineNum, "    storefile=""C:\storefile.xlsx"""
    LineNum = LineNum + 1
    CodeMod.InsertLines LineNum, "    msgbox ""Test display"""
    LineNum = LineNum + 1
    CodeMod.InsertLines LineNum, "    set workbooktostore = workbooks.open(storefile)"
    LineNum = LineNum + 1
    CodeMod.InsertLines LineNum, "    msgbox workbooktostore.readonly"
    LineNum = LineNum + 1
    CodeMod.InsertLines LineNum, "    workbooktostore.close"
    LineNum = LineNum + 1
    CodeMod.InsertLines LineNum, "end sub"
end sub
```

When you execute Main, this is resulting in ONE msgbox displaying "Test display". But when you click on save into the staellite1.xlsm, you should see the second msgbox displaying "false". I was expecting the same msgbox when SaveAs is executed...

Comment: I think your issue is related to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616366/import-and-run-macro-from-text-file/17616539#17616539). Maybe one of the answers there might help you.

Comment: Hi, thx but it seems to be different... My code is running well when i click on save within the satellite, but not when i programatically save the satellite.